# Formatting colors in dax

Tags: dax

I got six different measures shown as KPI cards. If the value is > then green, if the value <0 then red. Simple as that. The problem is that I have to make one measure for each (that is six extra measures), same goes for the arrows, 12 in total. How can I get all this into one measure so that one measure is controlling all the colors and arrows? I have tried manye different ways, but this only works for the first measure.

I want something like this working for each and every measure. This one will give "Green" to all of the measures because Measure 1 is positive. The rest is negative and should be "Red".

Comment: IF([Mesure1] > 0, "Green", "Red")
 IF([Mesure2] > 0, "Green", "Red")
 IF([Mesure3] > 0, "Green", "Red")
 IF([Mesure4] > 0, "Green", "Red")
 IF([Mesure5] > 0, "Green", "Red")
 IF([Mesure6] > 0, "Green", "Red")